# Views check access by PHP

Tags: views, users

I've got 2 roles on my system -uzman and isveren- and several views that need to be restricted to either uzman or isveren. For that purpose, I have been trying to check access control with PHP. I can't use role based access check because then administrator would see all because he has access to all views. Anyway, I am using

```
<?php
if (in_array("uzman", $account->roles)) {
return TRUE;
}
?>
```

which works, but I see many `undefined offset:4` messages in dblog (4 is uzman's rid). What is the correct way to check access with PHP in Views module?

Comment: Views already has plugins to check role and permissions. Why do you need to use raw PHP to do the same?

Comment: I can't check role-based access, because then the administrator would have access to them by menu as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to create a custom module and implement [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to define an appropriate permission:

```
function hook_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer my module'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Grant that permission to the roles that require access to it, and then use [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) to make the access decision:

```
if (user_access('administer my module', $account)) {
  ...
}
```

As AyeshK points out in the comments, you don't actually need the second part - Views has n plugin for access based permissions already, which you can configure through the UI. So once you've added the permission and granted it to the relevant role(s), it'll be easy to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay, I can do that; but how would I let users access the view within the if block?

Comment: Sorry I'm not following - the second code block above is what you use to determine access. Though you don't need to in the case of views, answer updated

Comment: I have to use PHP to determine access, because if I check by role administrator would have access to the view's menu as well, which is not what I want.

Comment: I was just answering your question: _What is the correct way to check access with PHP?_ (I actually missed the bit about the user 1 account first time round, apologies). Either way, if you don't want/can't use the correct way, then basically whatever works for your use case is the "correct way". Drupal doesn't have a "user access including the user 1 account" function, as the user 1 account is SU. It not having access to something could/should be considered a bug

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer with my question. Let me update it.

Comment: I think the update solidifies my last comment - if you look at the comments in `user_access()` you'll see _User #1 has all privileges_. That's a design decision at the very heart of Drupal, so trying to deny access to anything for user 1 is at odds with how Drupal is built. Ideally you should create a new role for site admins and assign the right permissions to that, leaving the super user to be what it's meant to be. Failing that, your current method is as good as you'll get really

Comment: What I want is not user #1 not having access to the view, but rather not having access to the menu I create. When I do a role-based access check, user #1 has access to the menu, which is not I want.

Comment: Those aren't 2 separate permissions, though. The permissions that govern a page also govern visibility of menu links to that page. User 1 is exempt from those by design. It'll probably take quite a bit of messing around to change user 1's intended role, your best option is to create a new role for site admins as I mentioned, or just use what you already have, which works. There's no better way to do it, as you're bypassing Drupal's core functionality